# HERE Traffic API: Does HERE provide data on accidents for Cape Town?

Tags: here-api

I'm using **HERE Traffic API** to get *incident data*, specifically data about *accidents*, for Cape Town.

Here is the link I'm using:
`https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?&apiKey=MY_API_KEY&bbox=-33.424531,18.208220;-34.398377,19.106580&type=Accident`

which always yields a result such as:
`{"TIMESTAMP": "08/26/2020 17:36:23 GMT", "VERSION": 2.4, "TIMESTAMP2": "2020-08-26T17:36:23.000+0000", "EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE": "NA"}` - no accident is reported.

If I don't filter by the type of incident, *i.e.* using the link:
`https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.3/incidents.json?&apiKey=MY_API_KEY&bbox=-33.424531,18.208220;-34.398377,19.106580`

I get data on other types of incidents and the **"EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE"** appears as **D0** - as it should since it is the market code for South Africa (as per https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/coverage-information.html).

Does the extended country code appear as **NA** when I filter by accident because HERE is not providing data on accidents for Cape Town? I've been able to filter the type of incident for other parts of the world so I guess there is no problem in how I am defining the link.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HERE does publish the accident data in South Africa. We also checked the data history internally, we do publish accident data for Cape Town.
I think when you get NA, mostly because there is no active accident at that time.

So far, we don't see any active accident event that has been missed but if you are aware of an active accident we missed please don't hesitate to let us know.

Comment: Many thanks HERE Developer Support! I have three further queries:
1) Is there a page on your website with the sources of your accident data? i.e. from where does HERE get the info that an accident has happened?
2) Do you have a page with the output data (incident data) metadata?
3) Does HERE provide historical accident data?

Comment: Many thanks @HERE Developer Support! I have three further queries: 1) Is there a page on your website with the sources of your accident data? i.e. from where does HERE get the info that an accident has happened? 2) Do you have a page with the output data (incident data) metadata? 3) Does HERE provide historical accident data?